# Skew line dense?

Tags: differential-geometry

Please let me refer you to:

> **Example 4.18.** The skew line $f: \mathbb R \to S^1 \times S^1$ 
>   $$
> f(t) = (e^{it}, e^{i\alpha t}).
> $$
>   If $\alpha$ is irrational then the image of $f$ is dense in $S^1 \times S^1$, so if $V$ is an open neighborhood of $f(t)$ in $S^1 \times S^1$, then 
>   $$
> \overline{V \cap f(\mathbb R)} = V
> $$ 
>   so $V \cap f(\mathbb R) \neq f(U)$.

(Source: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mat1300/smoothmaps.4.pdf, Page $16$, example $4.18$.)

Why is the image of the skew line dense (assuming $\alpha$ is not rational)?

Comment: This is called Kronecker winding on the torus. Have a look here: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially because, in $S^1$,  $e^{it}=e^{i(t+2\pi n)}$ for integer $n$, and the fractional part of $\alpha n$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: @user17182: which bit?

Comment: why the result follows from what you wrote? I don't see it

Comment: @user17182: If you are looking close to $\left(e^{i2\pi x},e^{i2\pi y}\right)$, consider $\left(e^{i2\pi (x+n)},e^{i2\pi (\alpha x+\alpha n)}\right)$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is enough to show that the intersection with $\{1\}\times S^1$ is dense in $S^1$. Because $\alpha$ is irrational, this intersection is infinite, so by compactness of $S^1$ it contains points arbitrarily close together. Take two such points and subtract their parameter values ...